# AngularJs ng-click not working with fileupload field

Tags: javascript, file, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am new to AngularJS, and I got stuck on this ng-click when trying to set some parameters before uploading an image. Here is the code:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div data-ng-click="readUploadedImage('grPhoto', '{{ id }}')">
        <label class="changePhotoBtn" for="uploadBanner">Click Here</label>
        <input style="display: none;" type="file" name="Upload a file" id="uploadBanner" />
    </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.id = 1234;

    $scope.readUploadedImage = function(parentClass, spid) {       
        alert(parentClass + ' ' + spid);
    }
}
```

Link to Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CMJkg/2/

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: Rename `function TestCtrl($scope)` to `function MyCtrl($scope)`

Comment: Sorry for the naming error. The problem is it never gets to the alert(). So the method called in ng-click never gets fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `readUploadedImage('grPhoto', '{{ id }}')` to `readUploadedImage('grPhoto', id)`. Expressions in ng-click are evaluated.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Sg6a/).